# Error while triggering quartz job in spring boot, kubernetes

Tags: spring, postgresql, docker, kubernetes, quartz-scheduler

I'm using Quartz Scheduler in Spring Boot with Postgres as Database. It was working fine in local enivornment with both dev and prod profile, but once we deployed the appliation in kubernetes. We got the error while triggering the job.

quartz.properties file

```
> org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=20
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold=60000
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval=20000
org.quartz.scheduler.classLoadHelper.class=org.quartz.simpl.ThreadContextClassLoadHelper
>
```

We received the following error

```
> org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't retrieve trigger: Bad value for type long : \x
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retrieveTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1538)
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.recoverMisfiredJobs(JobStoreSupport.java:984)
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doRecoverMisfires(JobStoreSupport.java:3264)
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$MisfireHandler.manage(JobStoreSupport.java:4012)
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$MisfireHandler.run(JobStoreSupport.java:4033)
> 

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type long : \x
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.toLong(PgResultSet.java:2878)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getLong(PgResultSet.java:2085)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getBlob(PgResultSet.java:417)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getBlob(PgResultSet.java:404)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getBlob(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.getObjectFromBlob(StdJDBCDelegate.java:3190)
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.selectTrigger(StdJDBCDelegate.java:1780)
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retrieveTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1536)
```

Comment: Please share your kubernetes manifest files...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your stacktrace, you are still using

```
org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
```

where your quartz.properties is set to

```
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
```

Therefore my guess is you are picking up wrong quartz.properties when it is running in kubernetes.